# Organise Imports (partially) not working for my own library in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I created a simple library project to be shared among my app projects. Currently there are two files in that library, each declaring a helper class with the same name as the .java file:

```
Util1.java --> public class Util1
Util2.java --> public class Util2
```

Initially `Util1` was not declared public.

For some reason Organise Imports command only detects the `Util2` class and auto-imports that, but not so with `Util1`.
Manually adding import for `Util1` works as it should, but I'd like an automatic import.

Naturally, I ran project clean multiple times already on both the library and the app project.

Edit: After adding some more classes, I find it that the problem is only in the one file. This particular file is `log.java` containing `class log` (lowercase for obvious reasons). This is the only file that declares its class lowercase so the problem seems to be connected to this fact.
I have tried renaming this file to L.java and a few other variants, but auto-import still didn't work. Naturally, before the file moved to the library and was part of the original project, it autoimported just fine.

How can I fix this so that ALL files will be properly recognised and auto-imported?

Comment: When the classes are placed in an own library project, maybe you didn't export the package the first class is located in? Also, please stick to the Java coding conventions and capitalize the first letter of your classes.

Comment: Export the package? Both .java files contain exactly the same package / class definition. Can you be more specific on what exporting the package means?

Comment: If they lie in the same package, forget my question. Perhaps you have multiple `Util1` classes which could be imported and Eclipse can't decide which one you want?

Comment: Both files are in src/com/xxx/lib folder

Comment: Check if class path is set correctly. if there are more than on files with same name in same package or different package then import won't work.